# Structured data accessibility page

Tags: accessibility, schema.org

This is proving tricky to find an answer for as structured data provides accessibility.

I know a bit about schema, I have added things like breadcrumbs, product info, etc. to the website so far (and Google recognised it and did cool things with it!!!

What I would like to know is what sort of structured data tags I can use on the page explaining the accessibility of a website.  For example can I add anything to help explain this bit: (if there is anything relevant!)

```
    <h2>Access Keys:</h2>
    <p>Most browsers support jumping to specific links by typing keys defined on the web site. Primary navigation links (sections) on this site use the following access keys:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Access key s &ndash;  skip to content</li>
        <li>Access key 0 &ndash; Home Page</li>
        <li>Access key 1 &ndash; Contact</li>
        <li>Access key 2 &ndash; Reps</li>
        <li>Access key 3 &ndash; Fees</li>
        <li>Access key 4 &ndash; About</li>
        <li>Access key 5 &ndash; Login / My Account</li>
        <li>Access key 6 &ndash; Join Us</li>
        <li>Access key 7 &ndash; Cart</li>
        <li>Access key 8 &ndash; Policies</li>
        <li>Access key 9 &ndash; Accessibility</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Depending on the web browser, please use following key combinations to use access keys:</p>
    <h4>Keystroke combinations</h4>
    <p>Different browsers use different keystrokes to activate accesskey shortcuts, as shown below:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Alt + [the accesskey]
            <ul>
                <li>Internet Explorer for Windows</li>
                <li>Chrome for Windows (not that Shift is required in some circumstances</li>
                <li>Safari for Windows</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Shift + Alt + [the accesskey]
            <ul>
                <li>Firefox for Windows</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Ctrl + Option / alt + [the accesskey]
            <ul>
                <li>Safari for Mac</li>
                <li>Chrome for Mac</li>
                <li>Firefox for Mac</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using the properties of http://schema.org/WebPage plus http://schema.org/Book etc, eg

```
<meta itemprop="accessibilityControl" content="fullMouseControl"/>
<meta itemprop="accessibilityHazard" content="noFlashing"/>
<meta itemprop="accessibilityHazard" content="MotionSimulation"/>
<meta itemprop="accessibilityHazard" content="Sound"/>
```

Further examples can be found on https://schema.org/accessibilityControl.

I found [this](http://www.designhive.com/blog/using-schemaorg-microdata) very helpful in deciding what to add.

The original proposal was described [here](http://www.a11ymetadata.org/accessibility-metadata-project-final-report/) before being accepted by schema.org, it still includes examples but I can't comment on the accuracy given the pace of change in structured data.

Answer (score 0):

In case Schema.org contains related properties, they would most likely be defined for the [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) type.

You’ll see that they define some accessibility-related properties, namely (as of [version 2.01](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.1)):

- [`accessibilityAPI`](http://schema.org/accessibilityAPI)
- [`accessibilityControl`](http://schema.org/accessibilityControl)
- [`accessibilityFeature`](http://schema.org/accessibilityFeature)
- [`accessibilityHazard`](http://schema.org/accessibilityHazard)

Possible values for these properties are listed on http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Accessibility.

You can apply these properties also to [`WebSite`](http://schema.org/WebSite) (or any other [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork)).

So it seems that there’s no property for listing access keys.

Comment: Thank you, I found that but couldn't work out what to do with it.  Was hoping the giant brains in here would know but I think you're right1

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is no. Accessibility should be considered as "usability for the disabled". Just like there's no way to indicate the usability level of your website in the source code, there's also no way to indicate the accessibility level.

If your doctype is HTML5, you may consider using [semantic sectioning tags](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp). Wrapping your navigation links in < nav > and your main content in < main > will greatly improve the accessibility of your web site. That should be enough to signal the search engines and assistive devices that your web site was developed with a consideration for accessibility.

Unless your product is a web application which will be repeatedly used by a closed user group, please consider removing the access keys all together. Access keys are only useful in a handful of situations and it's generally avoided by many accessibility professionals. Rather than relying on access keys, keep your HTML tidy, semantic and structured, that will do the trick.

Please read the [article on WebAIM](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey)

Comment: OK.  Thank you for the info on access keys, I didn't know that - I've always dutifully added them thinking I was being helpful!
I use <nav> etc. and structure carefully with h1 etc.
Thanks again.